# left_join duplicates even after troubleshooting

Tags: r, join, dplyr

Sample data:

```
    full<-structure(list(Location = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("AKS", 
"AOK", "BTX", "GTX", "HKS", "JKS", "LOK", "MKS", "MOK", "PKS", 
"SKS", "VTX"), class = "factor"), CT_NT = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("CT", "NT"), class = "factor"), Depth = c(5L, 
10L, 15L, 5L, 10L, 15L), Site = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), PW = c(22.8, 
21.5, 18.2, 22.5, 20.5, 19.2), BD = c(1.1, 1.2, 1.1, 1.3, 1.3, 
1.5)), .Names = c("Location", "CT_NT", "Depth", "Site", "PW", 
"BD"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

        osu<-structure(list(Location = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("AKS", 
"AOK", "BTX", "GTX", "HKS", "JKS", "LOK", "MKS", "MOK", "PKS", 
"SKS", "VTX"), class = "factor"), CT_NT = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("CT", "NT"), class = "factor"), Depth = c(5L, 
10L, 15L, 5L, 10L, 15L), pH = c(5.1, 5.4, 5.9, 5.2, 5.9, 6.2), 
    N = c(50, 31, 22, 35, 17, 8), P = c(122, 55, 34, 107, 23, 
    17), K = c(1301, 1202, 1078, 1196, 1028, 948), OM = c(2.3, 
    1.8, 1.5, 2.1, 1.4, 1.2), NH4 = c(19.3, 14.5, 11.6, 12.3, 
    8.6, 8.4), Sand = c(22.5, 25, 25, 25, 22.5, 18.8), Silt = c(56.3, 
    52.5, 50, 51.3, 52.5, 51.3), Clay = c(21.3, 22.5, 25, 23.8, 
    25, 30)), .Names = c("Location", "CT_NT", "Depth", "pH", 
"N", "P", "K", "OM", "NH4", "Sand", "Silt", "Clay"), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am trying to join two datasets using left_join in dplyr. To my astonishment, I'm getting duplicate rows that are somehow not being identified as such. After reading all the other answers I could get my hands on here that seemed to address "join" issues (at least I'm not the only one who has them...?), I have tried:

- Checking the group types of the joining variables in the two datasets
  to ensure they match
- Checking that I don't have duplicates within f1 or f2
- Checking that the categorical columns I'm using to join are, in fact,
  the same length and have the same contents. They're EXACTLY the same,
  all the way down to the order I put them in
- Explicitly specifying to dplyr to use Location, CT_NT, and Depth to
  join
- Letting dplyr figure out the joining variables itself Joining in both
  orders Using inner_join--I ended up with f1 only

I've used left_join before and not had this issue, and it was with a very similar dataset (the pilot data to this full study, in fact). I thought I understood what left_join was doing, but now I'm wondering if I don't actually. I'm trying to get better with using dplyr, but unfortunately it's a lot of me bashing away at things until something works *and* I can figure out why it worked so I can reproduce it again later as needed.

Given my inexperience, I'm sure the answer is going to be frustratingly straightforward and simple, to the annoyance of everyone involved. Such is the life of learning to code, I guess. Thank you in advance for dealing with a rookie's doofy questions!

Here's my code:

```
f1<-full %>% #Build pilot_summary. Pipe pilot to...
group_by(Location,CT_NT,Depth,Site) %>% #group_by to work on CT or NT at each site
summarise_at(5:6,funs(mean)) %>% #calculate site means
ungroup(f1) 
f1$Depth<-as.factor(f1$Depth)
f1$Site<-NULL

osu$Texture_Class<-NULL#Take out the texture class column
f2<- osu %>% 
group_by(Location,CT_NT,Depth) %>% #group because otherwise R tries to crash on the next line of code...
arrange(Location,CT_NT,Depth) %>% #Put everything in order like f1, just in case
ungroup(f2)
f2$Depth<-as.factor(f2$Depth)

full_summary<-left_join(f1,f2)
```

Comment: The code fails on my side, don't you mean `summarise_at(1:2,funs(mean)) ` or `summarise_at(c("PW","BD"),funs(mean))` ?

Comment: Could you give us the expected input ? unless I missed something you only told us that you want to "join" datasets, it can mean many things.

Comment: also I'm not sure why you give us `full` and `osu` (which are identical btw), instead of just giving us f1 and f2

Comment: I am also curious what the expected output is here. With the data you provided, the only additional variable you would get out of a join is `Site`.

Comment: Moody_Mudskipper: Regarding your first question, no, I don't. I mean columns 5 & 6, not columns 1 & 2. I could use "PW" and "BD", but I'd rather use the column numbers because then if for some reason I change the column names the code will still work without messing with it.

The expected output (I assume you mean expected output, not input, since I gave you the input) would be the f1 data with columns 4-12 from f2 tacked on to the right-hand side. I was under the impression that was the intent of left_join.

Comment: I messed up copying and pasting osu, so I'll fix that. I gave both because as I noted, I don't understand why it's not working and if it's something I'm doing in making f1 and f2 from full and osu, I wanted the code to be there.

Tylu: As I've noted, I messed up copying and pasting osu and it was supposed to be a different dataset-- I'm about to fix it. I replied to Moody_Mudskipper with the expected output! It will make more sense when osu is correct, I imagine... My mistake!